# TFS VSO REST API workitems (wit) paths give 404 errors

Tags: rest, tfs

I recently discovered that TFS has a RESTFul API and I am trying to pull information about workitems based on the documentation here: [Work Items](http://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/reference/reference-vso-work-item-work-items-vsi)

I've been able to get information about projects using this path:

[host]/tfs/TFS_DefaultCollection/_apis/projects

but when I try

[host]/tfs/TFS_DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems

or

[host]/tfs/TFS_DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems?version=1.0-preview

I get a 404 error.  I've tried a bunch of things based on various examples but I've not yet gotten anything back for any URI under the /wit/ path.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27300001/is-out-there-any-rest-api-for-tfs-2013-on-premises-installation) has an answer that suggests that this feature may not yet be supported in on-premises installations.  Has anyone gotten this to work?  There's a blurb about how you can get a 404 if you don't have premissions on the main [REST Basics page](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/get-started/get-started-rest-basics-vsi) for TFS.  Is there some authorization setting required or am I just going to have to wait for a later version?  We are running 2013 (Version 12.0.31101.0)

Comment: The VSO REST APIs are the *VSO* REST APIs.  They will arrive in on-premises TFS in the next major version.

Comment: If there *are* supported endpoints, make sure to double check the path.  The default collection's name is `DefaultCollection`, not `TFS_DefaultCollection`.

Comment: As noted above, DefaultCollection doesn't work for projects (or anything else that I've tried) but TFS_DefaultCollection **does** work for projects and teams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a 404 because those particular APIs aren't in the on-premise TFS 2013 product. They APIs are available from TFS *2015* CTP1 onwards.

Comment: I'm just using Visual Studio Online and have nothing on premise. I get the same error. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I think I figured it out.  I was looking for just a list of all work items but this only appeared to work if you include the Work Item ID's like this: DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems?ids=1&api-version=1.0