# Is there an API for TFS that you can use from other languages?

Tags: tfs

I see stuff about writing programs that access or update your data in TFS. But they all seem to be assuming that you will be working in C# (or other .Net languages). Behind the scenes I'm sure that's all just SOAP calls, or whatever Microsoft thinks is cool right now. But is that all documented somewhere so that I can access it from other languages like, say, Erlang?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any documentation on TFS Web Services?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227376/is-there-any-documentation-on-tfs-web-services)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is the [TFS OData](https://tfsodata.visualstudio.com/), the [TFS REST API's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27300001/is-out-there-any-rest-api-for-tfs-2013-on-premises-installation), and [TFS Java SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=22616).

The OData is useful for somethings, but not others, so have a look through the documentation and see if it will help you.

The REST API's are there for VSOnline, but still coming on-premise, the answer I linked to eludes to the fact you can use them on-prem.

The Java SDK is the same as the .NET one and can be used to do pretty much everything, it is what powers the Team Explorer Everywhere plugin for eclipse.